# Differences in DPI video between Raspberry Pi 3 B and 3 B+

Tags: display, pi-3b+

I have two identical setups with 5" TFT displays connected to Raspberry DPI hats. The SD card images are identical. The only difference is one is using a model 3B and the other a model 3B+. I have the 3B config.txt set up for 800x480 vertical display. The Pi(s) boot to the command line and I can access both using SSH. The 3B produces a clear image. The 3B+ is not driving the video HSYNC or VSYNC. What is the difference between models? 
Here is the config.txt

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# This configuration is for DPI 800x480
#---------------------------------------

# Disable spi and i2c, we need these pins.
dtparam=spi=off
dtparam=i2c_arm=off

# Set screen size and any overscan required
disable_overscan=1
overscan_left=0
overscan_right=0
overscan_top=0
overscan_bottom=0
framebuffer_width=480
framebuffer_height=800

# enable the DPI display
enable_dpi_lcd=1
display_default_lcd=1

# set up the size to 800x480
dpi_group=2
dpi_mode=87

# set up the hsync/vsync/clock polarity and format
dpi_output_format=454661

# set up the size to 800x480
hdmi_timings=800 0 40 48 88 480 0 13 3 32 0 0 0 60 0 32000000 6

display_rotate=1
gpu_mem=256
```

Comment: Your config file indicates your display is set to merely 480 wide by 800 tall.  Normally it's the other way around (800 wide by 480 tall).  Was this intentional?

Comment: Take the working SDCard from your 3B and boot it in your 3B+. You may need to run `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y` first if the 3B SDCard is too old for your 3B+.

Comment: The framebuffer is set to 480 wide by 800 tall because this is needed to get the display to be vertical.  "display_rotate=1" by itself is not enough.

Comment: Swapping the SD cards was the first thing I did. I have run update and upgrade. The only variable is the 3B+ Pi. I am wondering if there is something in the device tree that is different?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by adding

```
#Set DPI overlay mode
dtoverlay=dpi18
```

Now both versions of the Pi work the same.